# question from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, project

always when I open some project(which already exists) in eclipse I get this question

```
should referenced projects also be opened where applicable
```

what does it mean, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define dependencies between projects in your workspace. Go to a project's properties and then to "Project references".

Using this feature only makes sense if projects are connected to each other. For example if you have different Django sites and you have one project for each installed app. When opening the site project, you could have Eclipse automatically open the apps projects, too. (For want of a better example...)

Comment: @rookie: Just tick the checkbox and it won't annoy you again.